# Uploading large files but POST expires?

Tags: php, apache

I have a form on which the user uploads a file, a video file around 500mb, it takes over an hour sometime(slow and paintful) but when it does upload, seems like the $_POST has expired? Anyone could help?

Thank you!

Comment: What does "seems like the $_POST has expired" mean? What is actually happening?

Comment: 500meg via post? Ouch.... you'll need a PHP memory_limit higher than that, a post_max_size, etc... that allow such big files, and a heckuva long time_limit on the script.

Answer (score 1):

There are several directives you have to set up in the `php.ini`:

- [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)
- [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

and so on

**EDIT:** Didn't have time to finish the answer but you will need to set the memory limit and the time limit.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```

These settings will make the script to run without time or memory limits.

This may fix the situation but the script becomes quite vunerable to attacks. Also any network problems will break the upload which is something that happens quite often when uploading 500mb files.

Answer (score 0):

If `$_POST` and `$_FILES` are empty, most likely you exceeded the `POST_MAX_SIZE` allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Check `post_max_size` in `php.ini`. If it's anything less than your file size, there's your problem. You can read more here:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much must use chunking for large uploads over the Internet.  This can be possible with HTML 5 or Flash, prominent example being the YouTube uploader service.

Flash:

http://swfupload.org/

Multiple plugin support:

http://www.plupload.com/

Spiffy HTML5:

http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload